# VS KeyBinding working for key1="c" but not for key1="VK_LEFT"

Tags: command, key-bindings, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

The default Custom Command (i.e. Add new file -> Custom Command) in a new VSIX project triggers a message box when you click the menu item. I added the following to the .vsct to make the command triggerable via the shortcut <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>:

```
<KeyBindings>
    <KeyBinding key1="C" mod1="ALT" guid="guidFirstCommandPackageCmdSet" id="FirstCommandId" editor="guidVSStd97" />
</KeyBindings>
```

This works: <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> triggers the command.

However, when I change `key1="C"` to `key1="VK_LEFT"`the shortcut <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>left arrow</kbd> does not trigger the command... Nor does `VK_F5` or `VK_LBUTTON`.

I can't think of *any* reason why `alt+c` would work even though <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>left arrow</kbd> wouldn't, except for key binding conflicts, so I removed all shortcut bindings to <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>left arrow</kbd> in Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard, but to no avail.

Why does <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> trigger the command but <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>left arrow</kbd> does not?

Comment: When you're updating your .vsct, you're updating the number in the ProvideMenu attribute? Otherwise things might not take effect.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. All bindings work except VK_ prefixed ones